# Mysql regex to find fixed lenght words

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to find words of three letters from a given set using the next syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^[dcqaahii]{3}'
```

and it returns words with more than three letters. I thought that {3} limit the length of the output.

Any one know what's wrong in my expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXP`, unlike `LIKE`, does not have to match the whole string.  It only needs to match a portion of the string.

If you want columns that match your regex exactly, you need to include both the BOL and EOL characters in your regex:

```
'^[dcqaahii]{3}$'
```

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html) has more details.

Comment: Is there any way that do not use one letter more than once?

Comment: @domoindal: sounds like a good question for stackoverflow.com!  :-)

Comment: I'm trying many combinations with each letter with no good results. it gives me words that use a single letter more than once.

Comment: What I mean is, your new question is not related to the current question on MySQL's `REGEXP` operator.  Instead of pursuing it here, then, just [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specifically about regexs not matching duplicate letters!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the end of string anchor `$` to the end of your regex:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^[dcqaahii]{3}$'
```

Also, your can remove the extra `a` and `i` from your character class without changing the meaning: `^[dcqahi]{3}$`

Comment: One question F.J.: Is there any way to fetch only words whose letters are only within the given set and do not use them more then once?

Comment: @domoindal - did you ever find out how to fetch only words whose letters are only within the given set and do not use them more then once?

Comment: Not sure if MySQL regex supports it, but you could accomplish something like this is a lookahead and backreference, for example: `^(?!.*(.).*\1)[abc]{3}$` http://rubular.com/r/DJXE4pOqS1